# How to get variable to value format out of AWS secret manager?

Tags: grep, aws-secrets-manager

So we have our secrets stored in AWS Secret Manager, i can retrieve the secret using **awscli**

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id test | grep SecretString
```

but the output is in this format:

```
 "SecretString": "{\"REACT_APP_API_URL\":\"https://example.com/api\"}",
```

How can i get output like in this format

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=https://example.com/api
```

I'm really new to this so was thinking maybe its possible using **grep**?
Or if there's any way to retrieve from AWS in the above way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id XXXXX | jq --raw-output '.SecretString' | jq '.' | jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\")|.[]"`

that will do it

Broken down:

`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id XXXXX` retrieves specific secret

`jq --raw-output '.SecretString'` filters out only secret value

`jq '.'` formats is as json again (might not be necessary strictly speaking)

`jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\")|.[]"` remaps the json format to key=value

Comment: Could you also take time and explain the above command?